# Go to the beginning of the file

Tags: c, file-io

I want to read a file forever how can I go to the beginning of the file
Here is my code

```
FILE* inp_file=fopen("Input_file.bin","rb"); 
uint8* buffer; 
buffer=(uint8*)malloc(nSize);
uint32 nSize =1000;
while(1)
{
   while(! feof (inp_file))
     {             
         memset (buffer,'0',nSize); 
         fread (buffer,nSize,1,inp_file);
         Sleep(5);
     }
  //Here I want to go to the beginning of the file
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: use `void rewind ( FILE * stream );`

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to [fseek](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/fseek.html) and `SEEK_SET`

Also note that

```
uint8* buffer; 
buffer=(uint8*)malloc(nSize);
uint32 nSize =1000;
```

should be

```
uint8* buffer; 
uint32 nSize =1000;
buffer=(uint8*)malloc(nSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following seems to work for you. Best of luck :)

```
FILE* inp_file=fopen("Input_file.bin","rb"); 
uint8* buffer; 
buffer=(uint8*)malloc(nSize);
uint32 nSize =1000;
while(1)
{
   while(! feof (inp_file))
     {             
         memset (buffer,'0',nSize); 
         fread (buffer,nSize,1,inp_file);
         Sleep(5);
     }
  rewind(inp_file);
}
```